# Verify application for Loader.Io testing

Tags: c#

I am trying to do some load testing with

https://loader.io/

I am currently stuck at the stage of "verifying" my localHost application to make sure I am the one controlling it.

I have added this end point:

```
[HttpGet("/loaderio-a65421134i3ia3d110vcv0120d1ac14b/")]
[Authorize()]
public StreamReader GetLoaderIO()
{
    var file = System.IO.File.OpenText(@"C:\Users\User\Downloads\loaderio-a65421134i3ia3d110vcv0120d1ac14b.txt");
    return file;
}
```

When I run a GET request to this URL

http://localhost:5012/loaderio-a65421134i3ia3d110vcv0120d1ac14b/

I successfully step in my end point, what do I need to return in order for the LoaderIO to be happy? Do I have to return the stream so it can be downloaded?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see three potential issues with your code.

First, you are targeting a localhost address instead of a deployment address (i.e. http://yourapi.com or 159.254.102.69). To fix that issue you will need to either deploy your code somewhere or open http ports from your machine.

Second the file you are trying to retrieve my not be at the same location or might not even be accessible so a simpler way would be to write the string directly (done multiple time to verify on loader.io works like a charm) like below:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("loaderio-a65421134i3ia3d110vcv0120d1ac14b")]        
public HttpResponseMessage GetLoaderIoVerification()        
{       
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);       
        response.Content = new StringContent("loaderio-a65421134i3ia3d110vcv0120d1ac14b", Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");     
        return response;        
}
```

Finally, there is that `Authorize` attribute that will try to authenticate the loader.io request that needs to be a resource as accessible as this one: https://media4.giphy.com/media/LXONhtCmN32YU/giphy.gif In order to do so you will need to remove it.

Once those three points are corrected you will be able to verify your api for loader.io. Hope it helps.

Comment: I am currently getting this response throuhg postman ```{
    "version": {
        "major": 1,
        "minor": 1,
        "build": -1,
        "revision": -1,
        "majorRevision": -1,
        "minorRevision": -1
    },
    "content": {
        "headers": [
            {
                "key": "Content-Type",
                "value": [
                    "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "statusCode": 200,
    "reasonPhrase": "OK",
    "headers": [],
    "requestMessage": null,
    "isSuccessStatusCode": true
}```

Comment: I changed the code to follow your structure but it is still failing the verify test by LoadeIO, I am not concerned about any other structure since this is a test that will only be applied at my local box.
```[HttpGet("/loaderio-a65421134i3ia3d110vcv0120d1ac14b/")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetLoaderIO()
{
    var request = new HttpResponseMessage();
    request.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    request.Content = new StringContent("loaderio-a65421134i3ia3d110vcv0120d1ac14b");

    return request;
}```

Comment: Then you still have the first issue pointed by my answer, loader.io cannot access your localhost, you need to open run IIS on your local machine and open the ports using your IP. Once you made sure you can still run your query through your external IP, then you might be able to verify that on loader.io. However I am not sure of the result since I always provided registered domain names.

Comment: @IamNugele, yeah after some more research I just realized that LocalHost is not an option thank you I will post your answer as valid.